# Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of all finite unions of disjoint intervals of the form $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{R}$, $-\infty\leq a < b\leq \infty$. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Indeed, $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$: it suffices to take $a = -\infty$ and $b = \infty$.

If $A = (a,b]$, then $A^{c} = (-\infty,a]\cup(b,\infty)\in\mathcal{F}$ because $(-\infty,a]\in\mathcal{F}$, $(b,\infty)\in\mathcal{F}$ and the union is finite.

Finally, if $A = (a,b]$ and $B = (c,d]$, then one has that
\begin{align*}
A\cap B = (a,b]\cap(c,d] =
\begin{cases}
\varnothing & \text{if}\,\,(a\geq d)\vee(b\leq c)\\\\
(c,b] & \text{if}\,\,a \leq c < b \leq d\\\\
(a,d] & \text{if}\,\,c \leq a < d\leq b
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
which clearly belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. But $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Indeed, it suffices to consider the sequence of sets:
\begin{align*}
S_{n} = \left(a,b - \frac{1}{n}\right]\in\mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_{n} = (a,b)\not\in\mathcal{F}
\end{align*}
Consequently, $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Is there any theoretical flaw in my reasoning? Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: It should be "$-\frac{1}{n}$" but other than that your approach seems all right. you only forgot to argue that $\emptyset$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ but that's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have fixed it.

Comment: You haven't examined all the cases for how the two intervals can intersect.  You also haven't argued why it suffices to consider the intersection of two intervals when the sets in the algebra are finite unions of intervals (although this may follow from a proposition in whatever book you are using).